# Problems with sizes and lines in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a little question. I developed an application that automatically fills a data set obtained from a SQLite database. These data are drawn from dynamic way, and between the data I have a frame where I insert labels dynamically. I never know the exact number of labels inside these frame because I take data from different tables of my Database. The problem I have with the labels which texts within them do not fill within the width of the label. I tried to use `label.linebreakmode` but still makes the break. I post the code:

There I have many objects taken from previous code, like `widthFormato` and `widthImageFormato`

```
if([tipoVino length]!=0){
            UILabel *lblFormato = [[UILabel alloc] init];

            labelX = ((widthFormato-widthImageFormatos) / 2)+10;

            CGRect labelFrame = lblFormato.frame;
            labelFrame.size.width = widthImageFormatos;
            labelFrame.origin.x = labelX;
            labelFrame.origin.y = labelY+25;
            lblFormato.frame = labelFrame;
            lblFormato.numberOfLines = 0;
            lblFormato.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [lblFormato setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@",tipoVino]];

            lblFormato.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            labelY = lblFormato.frame.origin.y;
            [formatosImageView addSubview:lblFormato];

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sices" in the question title?

Comment: I read your question a few times and I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is exactly. Does the text flow off the screen when it's too long, instead of word-wrapping? Does the text word-wrap but the cell is too short (vertically) and the words run past the bottom of the cell? A picture or two could really help clarify.

Comment: @Neeku, I believe he means to say "sizes".

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, however I see you are setting numberOfLines to 0, however are not sending a message to sizeToFit. Could this solve whatever your problem is?

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth yeah, right, possible, but that didn't make sense to me either...

Comment: Sorry for the "sices". I try to explain in other words: In a Rectangle with sizes: 130w x 250h I insert Labels with sizes: 130w x 20h and when the text inside these labels is larger than 130w I need to automatically break line and make height=20*number of lines. Better now?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to send a message to sizeToFit after setting the text of the label, as this will resize the label to fit said text. You will probably also need to adjust the yPos of the label to account for different heights (assuming you want it to fit within a certain area).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to create labels with flexible height (not all have the same size), and must fix the width of formatosImageView.

**EDITED FOR iOS7**

I was using sizeWithFont that is deprecated in iOS7, I changed it for boundingRectWithSize

Try this:

```
UILabel *lblFormato = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblFormato.numberOfLines = 0;
lblFormato.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[lblFormato sizeToFit];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@", tipoVino];

[lblFormato setText: string];

//Calculate the size of the container of the lblFormato
CGSize size = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthImageFormatos, 2000) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"customFont" size:fontSize]} context:nil];

lblFormato.frame = CGRectMake(labelX, labelY + 25, size.width, size.height);
```

and you must update the labelY with:

```
labelY = lblFormato.frame.size.height;
```

Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Sending a message to sizeToFit where you are won't do anything as the label is empty at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer spinillos, but, [string sizeWithFont: ... I try but is deprecated in iOS 7.0 version

Answer (score 0):

With regards @spinillos answer, for iOS 7:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:<#fontSize#>] };
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithString: <#string#>,
                                               attributes:attributes];

CGRect frame = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(<#width#>, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
```

Comment: With this, the only change with my code is that appears .. at the end of the label.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, this code need the code of @spinillos?

Comment: @PlugInBoy Have you tried just doing [lblFormato sizeToFit]; after [lblFormato setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@",tipoVino]];